# How to update state in React before every component render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that looks like this:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myObject: this.props.myObject,
        };

        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.updateState();
    }

    updateState() {
        // removed for brevity, doing some calculations here
        // based on some data that is stored in Redux and is 
        // passed here as props.

        this.setState({
            myObject: newObject
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // removed for brevity, renders some HTML elements
        );
    }
}

MyComp.propTypes = {
    myObject: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    // some other props
};

export default MyComp;
```

The point is that I'm using Redux also, and when certain buttons are clicked on the rendered component, I update some state in the Redux, and the update works all fine. And afterwards based on the updated Redux state, I want to update the state of the `MyComp` component, which initially gets the state as a prop, though that object is not maintained in the Redux, but instead is a state of another component and it is passed to `MyComp` as a prop.

I simply want to update state before each render of the above component. But this doesn't seem to work. Although my data in the Redux is updated and works all fine, calling `componentWillMount` like this to update my local state, does not seem to work. What I have observed is that it calls my `updateState` function just one, it is not called in every re-render. Any ideas how to update the state before every render call?

Comment: What's the reason behind this? what do you want to achive by doing this ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I simply want to update my state before every time render method is called. But I guess `componentWillMount` is called just once, and not before each render of the component? Because what I observe is that my `updateState` function is called just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
```

React doesn’t call `componentWillReceiveProps` with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component’s props may update. Calling this.setState generally doesn’t trigger componentWillReceiveProps

So you can use `forceUpdate()` to re render the html.

You can get more detail here :

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

---

```
constructor(props) {
    ....
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
}

// this will be called when it receive props
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // you can also check props with current version
    // and set conditions to update state or not
    this.updateState();
}

updateState(){
    // removed for brevity, doing some calculations here
    // based on some data that is stored in Redux and is 
    // passed here as props.

    this.setState({
        myObject: newObject
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think `forceUpdate` is the right thing for me, as my component re-renders as often as it is needed, the problem is that my state is not updated in every re-render, while my `updateState` function inside the `componentWillMount` function is not called in every re-render. Will try with `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: will you please create a plunkr for this ? so i can help you more

Comment: I think I did not explain myself clearly. Just pay attention to my `updateState` function, it is doing some calculations, and as an end result it is updating my state. Now, what I want is that that `updateState` function to be called every time the component is re-rendered, including the initial rendering. In my current form, `componentWillMount` is called in the initial rendering, hence my `updateState` function is called in the initial rendering. But in the all other subsequent re-renders, `componentWillMount` is not called, hence my `updateState` function is not called.

Comment: @typos, if you need your state updated every time you re-render you should not be using the state really.

Comment: but you should not , beacuse the updateState is setting state, so it will re render the view , and if you call updateState on each re render, it will goes into infinite loop, though simple solution is call updateState direct inside render() before return.

Comment: @typos, try componentWillReceiveProps this is match your case exact.

Comment: @typos . You can very well write a  `componentWillReceiveProps` method and set your state as per the new props received . Your `componentWillMount` is not called again in the lifecycle of the component unless u unmount it. ie removing the component from DOM and mouting it again .  i think @Vivek has answered the original question ,unless we are missing something :)

Comment: > componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated since React 16.3.0, use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps